# how to html decode in a details view?

Tags: c#, tinymce, detailsview, html-encode

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateRows="False"
DataKeyNames="ID" DefaultMode="Insert" >
```

...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ShortExcerptTextBox" runat="server"
Text='<%#Bind("ShortExcerpt") %>' class="mceEditor"
TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

this is the code i have.

the problem is that i need to somehow `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` it there in the `#Bind("ShortExcerpt")` somehow, but don't know how.

the original issue is that tinyMCE (rich text editor) encodes the text by itself but does not decode it on read. a long story :P

**so please just, someone, explain, how to `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` the text that gets read into `#Bind("ShortExcerpt")` please?**

thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that you can use `HtmlDecode` with `Bind`.

So either try to `HtmlDecode` the TextBox in codebehind:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ShortExcerptTextBox" runat="server"
    Text='<%# Eval("ShortExcerpt") %>' 
    OnDataBinding="ShortExcerptTextBox_DataBinding" class="mceEditor"
    TextMode="MultiLine">
</asp:TextBox>


protected void ShortExcerptTextBox_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txt = (TextBox)sender;
    txt.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(txt.Text);
}
```

or try to use `Eval` instead(if that is acceptable):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ShortExcerptTextBox" runat="server"
    Text='<%# HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode((string)Eval("ShortExcerpt")) %>' 
    class="mceEditor"
    TextMode="MultiLine">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Both not tested yet.

Comment: perhaps you can help with the follow up question as well? sorry for the bother :( http://stackoverflow.com/q/10342792/101055 thnx